# Keras model learning to give wrong answers training accuracy raising to 0.8 to then deacrease dramatically down to 0.1

Tags: keras, neural-network

I'm going through the book "Deep Learning with Python" from François Chollet.

In section 7.9, there is an example neural network using Conv1D layers to process the IMDB dataset. What surprises me is that it starts to learn and both training and validation accuracy improve, but after a couple epochs, both the training as well as the validation accuracy drop.

Seeing the validation accuracy drop does not surprises me, it's quite typical of overfitting, but **what I don't understand is how the training accuracy can drop down to as low as 12%. It's almost as if the network was learning the opposite of what it should.**

The code is:

```
import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop

max_features = 2000
max_len = 500

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=max_len)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=max_len)

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(max_features, 128,
                           input_length=max_len,
                           name='embed'))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(5))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    epochs=20,
                    batch_size=128,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    # callbacks=callbacks,
                    )
```

And the training results are as follows:

```
Train on 20000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 4s 212us/step - loss: 0.7043 - acc: 0.6076 - val_loss: 0.4488 - val_acc: 0.8166
Epoch 2/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 151us/step - loss: 0.4509 - acc: 0.8179 - val_loss: 0.6575 - val_acc: 0.7594
Epoch 3/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 151us/step - loss: 0.4082 - acc: 0.7923 - val_loss: 0.4759 - val_acc: 0.7874
Epoch 4/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 152us/step - loss: 0.3633 - acc: 0.7526 - val_loss: 0.5385 - val_acc: 0.7356
Epoch 5/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 154us/step - loss: 0.3333 - acc: 0.7235 - val_loss: 0.5658 - val_acc: 0.7056
Epoch 6/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 152us/step - loss: 0.2793 - acc: 0.6868 - val_loss: 0.5790 - val_acc: 0.6494
Epoch 7/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 151us/step - loss: 0.2433 - acc: 0.6408 - val_loss: 0.6710 - val_acc: 0.5726
Epoch 8/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 149us/step - loss: 0.2061 - acc: 0.5789 - val_loss: 1.7192 - val_acc: 0.3538
Epoch 9/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 151us/step - loss: 0.1769 - acc: 0.5144 - val_loss: 0.8144 - val_acc: 0.4416
Epoch 10/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 151us/step - loss: 0.1507 - acc: 0.4365 - val_loss: 1.1555 - val_acc: 0.3682
Epoch 11/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 152us/step - loss: 0.1395 - acc: 0.3675 - val_loss: 1.1440 - val_acc: 0.3412
Epoch 12/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 156us/step - loss: 0.1241 - acc: 0.3159 - val_loss: 1.8202 - val_acc: 0.2686
Epoch 13/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 155us/step - loss: 0.1225 - acc: 0.2756 - val_loss: 1.0667 - val_acc: 0.2944
Epoch 14/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 152us/step - loss: 0.1183 - acc: 0.2422 - val_loss: 1.1143 - val_acc: 0.2794
Epoch 15/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 151us/step - loss: 0.1153 - acc: 0.2142 - val_loss: 1.1599 - val_acc: 0.2686
Epoch 16/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 153us/step - loss: 0.1150 - acc: 0.1930 - val_loss: 1.2467 - val_acc: 0.2544
Epoch 17/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 151us/step - loss: 0.1145 - acc: 0.1766 - val_loss: 1.1953 - val_acc: 0.2492
Epoch 18/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 153us/step - loss: 0.1115 - acc: 0.1508 - val_loss: 1.4812 - val_acc: 0.2226
Epoch 19/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 156us/step - loss: 0.1119 - acc: 0.1355 - val_loss: 1.2690 - val_acc: 0.2288
Epoch 20/20
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s 155us/step - loss: 0.1127 - acc: 0.1248 - val_loss: 1.2903 - val_acc: 0.2148
```

I could of course stop it early while the validation accuracy is at the top, but what I would is to understand how the training accuracy can drop so dramatically. And more surprisingly, how it can drop below 0.5, being a softmax 0/1 type output layer, I would expect the accuracy to be around 0.5. It really looks like it learns to give wrong answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael, thanks for the pointers on gradient explosion, I had not heard of this problem before.

What was really unusual with that network was that I was getting 12.5% accuracy for a classification problem with two answers with balanced samples. In the case the network is not learning I would have expected something around 50%.

Comming back to it after a break, I realized the problem is that the last Dense layer is missing an activation function. This would be OK for a regression problem, but not for a classification problem like this one. After adding activation='sigmoid' the network trains properly, with training accuracy raising continuously. It shows overfitting but that's expected.

So in short the problem was the use of the loss function `binary_crossentropy` with no activation function.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like exploding gradients or high variance. Try batch normalization before activations (or some other kind of regularization).

Use some easier model like the one below and work your way up:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(max_features, 128,
                           input_length=max_len,
                           name='embed'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.ReLU())
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.add(layers.ReLU())
```

Got to 70% after 20 episodes with that one.

Another problem could be too few examples in your data, try getting more samples, maybe through data augmentation, or reduce features.